# Create a button to copy entire Spreadsheet into a new word document

Tags: excel, copy, excel-2010, vba

Hello I am looking to program a button in an excel 2010 document that will copy the entire worksheet and automatically open and paste into a word document.

I have been looking on the help pages, and there is some similar functions, but they are too specific and i can't get the code to work.

Here is the code i was using
The example i was going from was stating a range, and i can do it that way, or just copy the entire worksheet (called "outputCMCR") into a new word document.
When i run this code i get a Compile Error, User defined type is not defined.

```
Sub button2_click()  

    Dim objWord As New Word.Application  
    'Copy the range Which you want to paste in a New Word Document  
    Range("A1:B10").Copy  

    With objWord  
        .Documents.Add  
        .Selection.Paste  
        .Visible = True  
    End With  

End Sub
```

Thanks any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I think there are 2 issues here

1- Have you referenced `Microsoft Word 14.0 Object Library`? To do this, click on `Tools -> References` (in your VBA editor). Scroll down the list until you see the *`Microsoft Word 12.0 Object Library`* or *`Microsoft Word 14.0 Object Library`* (depending on which version of Office is installed on your machine) and select it. [Read this](http://msofficefun.wordpress.com/2011/02/26/early-binding-vs-late-binding-in-office-vba/) for *early and late binding*

2- You would need to create object like the code below

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim objWord As Word.Application
    Range("A1:B10").Copy

    Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application.14")
    With objWord
        .Documents.Add
        .Visible = True
        .Selection.Paste
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I tried your addition to the code, but still getting the same error.  What do you mean in your 1st issue, have i referenced word 14 object library.  I'm sure I haven't because I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: @ShawnLasich - I've updated the answer. Hope this resolves the error.

Comment: Your revised answer solved the problem that I was having, thank you so much for your assistance!!